# Closed form for a recursive sequence: reference request

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, closed-form

Playing around with [this WolframAlpha widget](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=6060d322713797e84f598ea25c812cab), I found that the sequence satisfying
$$f(n)=4f(n-1)+2f(n-1)^2$$
and
$$f(1)=4$$
is given by
$$f(n)=\cos(2^{n-1}\cos^{-1}(5))-1.$$
Could you tell me where I could read about the general theory leading to such a result?

Comment: $\cos(\cdots)-1\in[-2,0]$ while with $f(1)=4$ then all $f(n)\ge 4$, surely this is not working!

Comment: @zwim This uses complex continuations of the usual $\cos$ and $\cos^{-1}$ trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually, cosine is inappropriate   as $f(1) = 4,$   unless you are willing to keep a bunch of complex coefficients.  You want $a_{n+1} = 2 a_n^2 + 4 a_n,$  and I am going to shift so $a_0 = 4$

The recursions that come out well are $d_{n+1} = d_n^2$   and $c_{n+1} = c_n^2 - 2$

For your question, take  $c_{n+1} = c_n^2 - 2$

Then take  $$ a_n = \frac{c_n}{2}  -1 $$
With this, it turns out
$$ a_{n+1} = 2 a_n^2 + 4 a_n$$

You need to find $c_0,$   then there is a real quantity
$$ c_0 = W + \frac{1}{W},  $$   after which
$$c_n = W^{2^n} + \frac{1}{W^{2^n}},  $$
from $a_0 = 4$ we need $4 = \frac{c_0}{2}   - 1$ or $c_0= 10,$   we may take
$$  W = 5 + \sqrt{24}$$  with reciprocal $5 - \sqrt{25}$

$$c_n = \left(5 + \sqrt{24} \right)^{2^n} + \left(5 - \sqrt{24} \right)^{2^n} $$

and
$$ a_n = \frac{c_n}{2}  -1 $$

Comment: Hi, Will ; I thought at first to a connection with Chebyshev polynomials (because of the expression with cosines) but your treatment is the right one !

Answer (score 1):

$$f_n=4f_{n-1}+2f_{n-1}^2$$
$$f_n=g_n-1 \quad \implies \quad g_n=2g_{n-1}^2-1$$ Here, we see appearing the solution (double angle formula for the cosine)
$$g_n=\cos(h_n)\quad \implies \quad \cos(h_n)=\cos(2 h_{n-1})\quad \implies \quad h_n=2^{n-1}\,C$$ Therefore
$$g_n=\cos(2^{n-1}\,C)\quad \implies \quad f_n=\cos(2^{n-1}\,C)-1$$
$$f_1=4 \implies \cos(C)=5\implies C=\cos ^{-1}(5)\quad \implies \quad f_n=\cos \left(2^{n-1} \cos ^{-1}(5)\right)-1$$ as given by Wolfram Alpha.

But $$\cos ^{-1}(5)=i \cosh ^{-1}(5)\quad \implies \quad \color{red}{f_n=\cosh \left(2^{n-1} \cosh ^{-1}(5)\right)}$$

$$f_7=2610701117696295981568349760414651575095962187244375364404428800$$